# Spring Integration Event Listener Inbound Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, event-listener, spring-integration-dsl

I've got a question, i want to implement an input adapter in spring integration using dsl, as an event listener and redirect messages from that event listener to a channel.

desired code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow listenerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(InputAdapterListener.listen())
            .channel("ChannelXYZ")
            .get();
}
```

can someone explain to me what would be the implementation of the InputAdatperListener class to support a behaviour like this, or where to look for some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` in the `spring-integration-event` for you to use in that `from()` configuration:

```
 private ApplicationListener<?> applicationListener() {
        ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer producer = new ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer();
        producer.setEventTypes(TestApplicationEvent1.class);
        producer.setOutputChannel(resultsChannel());
        return producer;
    }

... 

 IntegrationFlows.from(applicationListener())
```

And this one is going to be registered as a bean automatically.

Comment: However, if you are not talking about Spring Application events but some other event source, then you would extend `MessageProducerSupport` and call `sendMessage()`.